# Error in Hangman Game

Tags: java

I am trying to make a hangman game where the computer randomly pulls a word from the array, but I can't seem to connect it to the main class.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.getRandom(args);
    Prompter prompter = new Prompter(game);
    while(game.getRemainingTries() > 0) {
        game.display();
        prompter.promptForGuess();
    }
}

}

//Prompter class
public boolean promptForGuess() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a letter to guess: ");
    String guessInput = scanner.nextLine();
    char guess = guessInput.charAt(0);
    return game.applyGuess(guess);
}

public void displayProgress(String progress) {
    System.out.printf("You have %d tries left to solve: %s%n",
                      game.getRemainingTries(),
                      game.getCurrentProgress(progress));

//Game class
public String getRandom(String[] array) {
    random = myString[(int) (Math.random() * myString.length)];
    return random;
}
public String display(String random) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < random.length(); i++ ) {
        str.append("-");
    }
    System.out.println(str.toString());
    return str.toString();
```

I'm expecting it to show up as dashes for the amount of letters in each random word(fluctuates depending on the length of the random word)

This is the error I get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: The method display(String) in the type Game is not applicable for the arguments () at Main.main(Main.java:9)

Do I need to pass an argument into the game.display()? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *Do I need to pass an argument into the game.display()* - yes.

Comment: what do I put in there? iv'e tried random, progress, and others but to no avail...and who downvoted me? its a perfectly good question, this community is toxic lol

Comment: I didn’t downvote...but you should have put your efforts to remedy the situation in your post so people know what you’ve tried.

Comment: oh ok thank you! the other guy fixed it who told me to take out the String parameter but he removed his post lol

Comment: I put it back. I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the String paramater from your display method as it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a `String` to you display method.

Example:

```
game.display("String value here");
```